# Amazon SES reading emails stored in an s3 bucket using java from S3ObjectInputStream object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I have configured my `AWS SES` to store all incoming emails to an S3 bucket with Object key Prefix as Email. I have a Java application using with I am trying to read all objects in that bucket and then move them to another so that only the unread emails remain in the bucket. I use the following code:

```
public class FileReadImpl 
{
    private static final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileReadImpl.class);

    AmazonS3 s3;

    public void init(String accessKey, String secretKey) 
    {
      s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
    }


    public List<S3ObjectInputStream> readEmailsAndMoveToRead(String accessKeyId, String secretAccessKey, String incommingBucket, String processedBucket)
    {
        List<S3ObjectInputStream> s3ObjectInputStreamList = new ArrayList<S3ObjectInputStream>();
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
            ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects(incommingBucket, "Email/");
            List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();

            while (listing.isTruncated()) 
            {
               listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
               summaries.addAll (listing.getObjectSummaries());
            }
            for (S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary : summaries) 
            {
                String key = s3ObjectSummary.getKey();//getting the key of the item
                S3Object object = s3.getObject(
                          new GetObjectRequest(incommingBucket, key));
                S3ObjectInputStream  inuptStream = object.getObjectContent();
                s3ObjectInputStreamList.add(inuptStream);
                if(!s3.doesBucketExist(processedBucket))
                {
                    s3.createBucket(processedBucket);
                }
                s3.copyObject(incommingBucket, key, processedBucket, key);
                s3.deleteObject(incommingBucket, key);
                try 
                {
                    inuptStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    logger.error(e.toString());
                }
            }
        return s3ObjectInputStreamList;
    }
}
```

I have another service class that access the above class to get the list of emails and store them to my database. The code is as shown below:

```
public void getEmails()
{
    FileReadImpl fileReadImpl = new FileReadImpl();
    List<S3ObjectInputStream> s3ObjectInputStreamList = fileReadImpl.readEmailsAndMoveToRead("accessKeyId", "secretAccessKey", "incomingBucket", "processedBucket");
    for (S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream : s3ObjectInputStreamList) 
    {
        //logic to save the email content as emails
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to get the email content, the senders details, the cc details etc from the `S3ObjectInputStream` object that I have. How do I process this object to get all the details I need.

Comment: hi, were you able to find a good solution ?

Comment: @rmagon , I have used the solution below and it works

Comment: @GeoThomas can you please tell me how you setup the AWS SES to configure on S3? I have done the same but for some reason receiving email from only one email. That email is the same I have registered the website with. can you shed some light on this please? or if you can point me to the right thread that would also be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the inputstream to a MIME Message which can be done as follows:

```
for (S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary : summaries) 
{
    String key = s3ObjectSummary.getKey();//getting the key of the item
    S3Object object = s3.getObject(
              new GetObjectRequest(incommingBucket, key));
    InputStream mailFileInputStream = object.getObjectContent();
    String bucketKey = object.getKey();
    MimeMessage message = getMimeMessageForRawEmailString(mailFileInputStream);//converting input stream to mime message
    object.close();
}

public MimeMessage getMimeMessageForRawEmailString(InputStream mailFileInputStream) throws Exception
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, mailFileInputStream);
    return message;
}
```

Once you have the Mime message, use a parser to read the contents from that message:

```
MimeMessageParser parser = new MimeMessageParser(message);
String from = parser.getFrom();
String htmlContent = parser.parse().getHtmlContent();
System.out.println("Body: "+htmlContent);
String plain = parser.parse().getPlainContent();
System.out.println("plain: "+plain);
```

This way, you will be able to read all the contents of the email stored as an S3 object in an S3 bucket

Comment: I am getting duplicate attachments doing so...